# Google play app rejected because of REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission

Tags: android, permissions, google-play-console

We have a app on google play store something like snapchat (Social Networking App) but with advance chat features including app package installs. Our app got removed from playstore because we are using  REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission and google thinks it's not core purpose of our app. As per the document for REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission state

> *Communication services that support attachments;*

can request this permission. Our app has inbuilt chat functions which supports communications with chat attachments(APK). Where whatsapp,telegram etc can have this permission too.

We mentioned this in our policy section

> Our app has chat feature which enable users to shares different types
> of attachments including APK. To install APK inside our app we need
> REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES which help users to share and install APK.
> It's same like other messaging app like telegram,whatsapp etc.

And selected `communication services that support attachments &  file sharing, transfer or management`
`Which permitted functionality does your app provide` section and  `App functionality` in `Why does your app need to use the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission` section

Are `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` is invalid for our app because every other messaging app having this permission and we are getting rejecting even after appeal. Can anyone put insight on this issue please.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: @CommonsWare You mean i need to ask this at meta?

Comment: No, I mean that you need to ask this somewhere outside of the Stack Overflow universe.  You might try Reddit or other Android developer support sites, or perhaps discussing options with your attorney.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok i will ask on others too but whats your view on my issue. I am right to ask permission or google is right to reject app update?

Comment: Personally, I have no idea why any social network client or messaging app should be installing other apps.